# Where did the guy with laser eyes come from?

Tags: dc, arrowverse, the-flash-2014

In the last two episodes of Flash Season 1 we see all of the characters Flash has

> imprisoned beneath STAR Labs

use their metahuman abilities

> when Captain Cold helps them escape captivity

Of course, 4 of these characters are familiar to anyone who has watched the show to that point:

- Nimbus
- Mardon
- Baez
- Bivilo

They were each the focus of at least one episode, and we are aware of their powers.  With them was a fourth man, who hadn't been the subject of an episode.  Flash was obviously aware of who he was and what his powers were, but it came as a big surprise to me when he shot lasers from his eyes.

Who is this character, and how did he end up in that situation?  When was he first introduced?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That would be DeathBolt, introduced in Arrow.

[image]

seen in Arrow Season 3 "Broken Arrow" and Flash season 1 "Rogue Air"

> Jake Simmons, nicknamed Deathbolt by Ray Palmer, was a meta-human who had the power of shooting plasma through his eyes and absorbing electricity. He was the only known meta-human to have not been in Central City during the particle accelerator explosion. He was imprisoned in the S.T.A.R. Labs particle accelerator, but he, along with the rest of the imprisoned meta-humans, were eventually freed by Leonard Snart and Lisa Snart. However, he was killed by Leonard with his Cold Gun because he said he owed him money.

[arrow wiki](http://arrow.wikia.com/wiki/Jake_Simmons)

> He was fought and captured by The Atom during the episode "Broken Arrow", and then locked up back in Central City with the other meta-humans.